# Is there a physical interpretation of the "test function" for weak solutions to differential equations?

Tags: hyperbolic-equations

**Background**

Consider the inviscid Burgers' equation.
\begin{align*}
u_t + f(u)_x&=0
\end{align*}
or, using $f(u)=\frac{1}{2}u^2$,
\begin{align*}
u_t + u u_x &=0
\end{align*}
In the case of non-smooth initial data $u_0(x)$, a classical solution does not exist.

A function $u(x,t)$ is called a weak solution if
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi_t u + \phi_x f(u) dxdt = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(x,0)u(x,0)dx
$$
for all test functions $\phi \in C_0^1(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+)$

**Question**

Is there a way to gather some physical intuition about the meaning of this condition? Looking at the right hand side, the integral is a sort of weighted average of $\phi$ by the concentration $u$. But what would the left hand side represent?

I'm fine with simply using the test functions as a mathematical tool - but it is somewhat disappointing to abandon the wonderfully intuitive "control volume" formulation of a weak solution:
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} u(x,t_2)dx = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} u(x,t_1) dx + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} f(u(x_1,t))dt - \int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(u(x_2,t))dt
$$
i.e., the concentration of $u$ in the control volume at $t_2$ is simply whatever was in the volume at $t_1$ plus the net flux into the volume.